# Наидлиннейший путь в графе

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Есть неориентированный взвешенный в общем случае граф. Как найти в нем кратчайшие пути - известно. Но мне хочется найти наидлиннейший путь между двумя вершинами в графе.

Конечно, если в графе есть циклы, то задача решения не имеет. А если задать вопрос как "наидлиннейший ациклический путь между вершинами"? Кажется, такой путь должен быть? Не укажете, каким алгоритмом это можно посмотреть?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задача_о_самом_длинном_пути